# teamcity 2017.1.1 artifactory plugin release management

Tags: plugins, teamcity, artifactory, release-management, maven-release-plugin

We are using TeamCity with the Artifactory plugin, utilising the release management functions for Maven builds.

However, I have just upgraded TeamCity from 8.1.4 to 2017.1.1 and following a successful run of a Release build using the Artifactory Release Management tab, the subsequent build displays a link to the build info but not the Artifactory Release Promotion.

We are running Artifactory Pro 4.15.0, v.2.3.1 of the plugin.

Any ideas why it might not be available?

We have a teamcity-server.log entry:

```
[2017-05-30 16:40:04,149]  ERROR -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - Error java.lang.InstantiationException: bean buildId not found within scope while processing request: GET '/viewLog.html?buildId=1151702&tab=buildResultsDiv&buildTypeId=XXXXXXX_Compile', from client 162.11.60.209:58332, authenticated as XXXXXXX {id=2} 
java.lang.InstantiationException: bean buildId not found within scope
            at org.apache.jsp.plugins.artifactory.promotionResultsFragmentExtension_jsp._jspService(promotionResultsFragmentExtension_jsp.java:136)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see this issue addressed in JIRA [TCAP-293][1]. This bug will be fixed in the next release of the TeamCity plugin which is scheduled for the end of June.